# MySQL: trying to create table by joining 2 tables on the same key name

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table by joining 2 tables on the same key name.

```
create table join_ as 
select *
FROM sakila.film_actor fa  join sakila.film_category fc
on fa.film_id = fc.film_id;
```

It returned this:

> Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'film_id'

It works OK if I only select columns instead of creating a table. How could I do this without exhaustively listing all column names or altering original table? Is there any way to drop one of the 'film_id' or change it?

Thanks!!! I am new to SQL and hope I have described my problem properly.

Comment: You will need to list the column names. You could select fa.* and list only those in fc (or visa-versa).

Comment: How difficult is it to copy column names from the result of a select query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a [Natural Join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Natural_join):

```
create table join_ as 
select *
from film_actor fa natural join film_category fc
```

Use this with care as this will merge *all* equally named columns into one each.

Comment: This works! Thanks! But this brings me to another question. What if there's a common key that's not relevant for the merging. Let's say a column named "last_update_time". Two tables were updated on different time and surely you wouldn't want to join the table on this.

Comment: In a DML query, a natural join is usually not the way to go. But you're creating a new table and want to avoid providing all the column names. Here I find it kind of logical, that equal columns get merged into one and the new table will not / can not contain two columns with the same name.

Comment: @Xingru Deng Your example `last_update_time` is metadata, which would be better in a different (6NF temporal) table and for the exact reasons you allude to!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `*`. There are two columns with the same name. When creating a table all column names must be different. As an example you could do something like:

```
create table join_ as 
select
   fa.film_id as a_film_id, 
   fc.film_id as c_film_id
  FROM sakila.film_actor fa
  join sakila.film_category fc on fa.film_id = fc.film_id
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes. Star is the problem! This works perfectly. But if I write the query in this way, I could end up with writing more column names than I want to.Checking for omission will blind me. Is there an elegant way to use * and rename a certain column by the same time?

Comment: I wish it were. The best thing I can figured so far is to pick the table with the biggest number of columns and use the `*` on that one; then I type the FULL list of column names on the other one: `select a.*, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3 ...`

Answer (score 0):

It is general better to list the the columns explicitly, particularly for a view.  If you do not want to, you can use the `using` clause:

```
create table join_ as 
    select *
    from sakila.film_actor fa join
         sakila.film_category fc
         using (film_id);
```

This will work if `film_id` is the only common column name between the tables.

I strongly, strongly, strongly discourage you from using `natural join` for this purpose.  First, it uses *all* columns that have the same name.  So, if another column has the same name (such as `createdAt` in most tables I create), then the `join` will probably filter out rows.  Debugging such a problem is very hard.  And, adding a column to either table -- after the view is created -- can cause it to fail.

I describe `natural join` as an abomination, specifically because it does not use properly declared foreign keys for the `join` keys.  Instead, it just uses columns that happen to have the same name.

Comment: Thanks! This saves me time on writing the 'on' clause. However it results in dulplicate column name, too.

Comment: @XingruDeng . . . What duplicate column name?  The duplicate will not be `film_id`.

Comment: Your example `createdAt` is metadata, which would be better in a different (6NF) table and for the exact reasons you allude to!

Comment: "`[NATURAL JOIN]` just uses columns that happen to have the same name" - by design. A database language with natural join as the only join type would be relationally complete; if it relied on FKs it would even qualify as a database language. You are expecting `NATURAL JOIN` to do something that makes no sense from a database language design point of view.

Comment: Now, a tool to help users write SQL queries using auto-complete or 'IntelliSense' based on FKs in the data dictionary you might find useful. The idea behind natural join is that you design your schema to avoid join types that are verbose, generate duplicate columns that must be qualified using range variables, etc. But I think you know all this and are looking at things in an obtuse way to make some kind of point.